# How to insert Api value in NgForm Angular post request hardcoded

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

so I'm making a crypto-exchange project in angular using .net as backend. Result of project is that a user can make a purchase that is saved in database using post request. I'm using ngForm for it and can make whatever input field I wand, and everything is working, but I want to post live price of bitcoin multiplied by inputed amount.

This is my html:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmitB(form)">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="service.formData.id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <h3 style="color: black;">Amount</h3>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="amount"
            #amount="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formDataBk.amount">
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <h3 style="color: black;">Total price</h3>
        </label>
        <p type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="currentPrice" 
           #currentPrice="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formDataBk.currentPrice"> 
           {{coinPrice*service.formDataBk.amount || 0}}</p>
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <h3 style="color: black;">Crypto Adress</h3>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg"
            #cryptoAdress="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formDataBk.cryptoAdress">
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">CONFIRM</button>
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
```

So far I made the value live bitcoin price * amount here : `{{coinPrice*service.formDataBk.amount || 0}}`, it works, and show's the price, but I want it to be saved in database with other stuff I insertet in Input field. I know that with

it won't work, but I don't know what to insert, I tried a bunch of thing, but it won't sent the result of this coinPrice*amount to database... What can I do?
Post request works fine, live api work, everything I insert in input field works correctly.

This is my TS file with functions:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { coinApiService } from 'src/app/shared/coinApi.service';
import { TransactionService } from 'src/app/shared/transaction.service';
import { TransactionBbuy } from 'src/app/shared/transactionB.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buy-btc',
  templateUrl: './buy-btc.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class BuyBtcComponent implements OnInit {
  result: any;
  coinPrice: any = [];
  
  constructor(public service: TransactionService, private toastr: ToastrService, private price: coinApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.btcPrice();
  }

  btcPrice() {
    this.price.coinsPriceBTC().then((res) => {
      this.result = res;
      this.coinPrice = this.result.bitcoin.eur;
      console.log(this.coinPrice);
    })
  }

  onSubmitB(form: NgForm) {
    
    this.service.postTransactionBk().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.toastr.success('Uspješno!', 'Podnešen zahtjev za transakciju')

      },
      err => { console.log(err); }
    );
  }

  resetForm(form: NgForm) {
    form.form.reset();
    this.service.formDataBk = new TransactionBbuy();
  }
}
```

I'm stuck with this past 2 day's, and after this my project is finished, I'm grateful for all help I get :D

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the **basic principles** what you're missing, unfortunately not just from angular, but also from designing disconnected / distributed systems and probably also some domain knowledge about financial systems.

#### Angular:

The text interpolation {{ }} inside Angular is great for displaying values. You can use `{{ coinPrice * service.formDataBk.amount || 0 }}`.
But that's it - all what you get is that a computed value gets displayed.

If you want the same value to be sent via a HTTP POST, you will need to calculate it in the TypeScript code. This also means that when you want to apply DRY, you're better of writing a getter inside the TS code:

```
public get bitcoinRate(): number { 
    return this.coinPrice * this.service.formDataBk.amount || 0; 
}
```

The next part you need it to pass any value to the HTTP POST method (via uri path / query / body). So the method you mentioned should have this definition:

```
this.service.postTransactionBk({ } as IDataToPost)
```

Please check out the quide: https://angular.io/guide/http

#### Now the architecture:

There's a basic problem with the design: usually you can POST how many of a given item you want to buy, but not the rate. The rate is usually guarded by the service provider.

In some systems you usually place a buy order and have different options. With bank and buying currencies (where rate changes seldomly - usually it's fix for a day) you're ok to place a buy order.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeNG1S5teZ0&t=353s

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your help, I have it solved in some other way, but your approach is more professional one, and I need a little time to study it, because I'm a little bet of a noob. :D